# how to save html to variable?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I try to save wysiwyg data to a variable but I keep getting a error message

**"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"**

And I cant get my head around it... I can se in the console that everything 
is retrieved ok, anyone with an idea of what could be the error.

javascript

```
var temp = "<?php echo $pressDescription ?>"
```

console[image]

Comment: You've got to encode the html code and then when you come back to show you've got to decode it.

Comment: I see very little `;` in your javascript. And no end `"` in the value of the `var temp` line

Comment: @Danny — Only one statement is missing it (and that is legal since JS supports semi-colon insertion).

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape characters which have special meaning or are not allowed in JavaScript string literals (such as new lines).

The `json_encode` function will do that for you.

```
var temp = <?php echo json_encode($pressDescription); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use escape characters. For example:

```
var varName1 = '<p class="className">Sample text</p>';
var varName2 = '<p class=\'className\'>Sample text</p>';
var varName3 = "<p class=\"className\">Sample text</p>";
```